# Google Cloud Billing - Filter By Label Not Showing

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I added resource labels to a few VMs to be able to pull a more granular billing breakdown by label. However, when I go to the billing report, I don't see any option to filter by Label. Is this a permission issue or am I missing something?

If I embed "label=" in the url, the label option will show, but it still doesn't retrieve the matching key pair.

Answer (score 0):

As per my analysis your issue can be due to below reasons :

- As per the [official doc](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-labels#what-are-labels) it says that

> When filtering your billing breakdown by label keys, you are not able
> to select labels applied to a project. You can select other
> user-created labels that you set up and applied to Google Cloud
> services.

This might be the reason you are unable to filter the label.

- Google does not recommend creating large numbers of unique labels,
  such as for timestamps or individual values for every API call. Refer
  to these  [common use cases for labels](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-labels#common-uses)  and Refer this [link](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-labels#requirements) for
  requirements of label.
- You need to enable “resourcemanager.projects.get “ [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-labels#permissions) and
  also enable “resourcemanager.projects.update”  to add or modify the
  label.
- Refer to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-labels#create-labels) to create the label.

Comment: You can also contact [Cloud billing Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing?_ga=2.244193733.-1596543797.1671645178).